Есть ли множественное число у слова «бизнес»?
Есть ли множественное число у слова «бизнес»?

Портал «Грамота.ру»:


На данный момент в Национальном корпусе русского языка представлен 61 пример со словом «бизнесы» (и это только в именительном и винительном падежах).
Уместность использования множественного числа этого слова нужно определять в контексте.

Например, стало нормой для бизнесов Китая

@Наталья Посмотрите три ответа справочной службы "Грамоты". Может, это поможет Вам определиться. Там пишут, что в профессиональной речи такое допустимо. Честно говоря, мне не нравится мн. число, но со временем слух привыкнет :)

спасибо, интересно)
